# How to use trasaction method inside a then() method firebase cloud function?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to run a transaction operation in the second `then()` method that is like

```js
return admin.database().ref(/Posts).child(oldPostKey).transaction();
```

Is it correct to do this as shown in the code? There is no error in the Firebase console function log when I execute it, but it does return anything to the next `then()` method. `admin.database().ref(/Posts).child(oldPostKey)` has more than one child. Now in the next `then()` method I want to get all the values of the child for further processing. Can anyone help me?

```js
exports.newIdGenerator = functions.database.ref('/User/{fixedId}').onCreate((shot, context) => {

    const fixedId = context.params.fixedId;
    const totalLikeRef = admin.database().ref(`/TotalLike`).child(fixedId);
    var totalAmount;

    return totalLikeRef.transaction((totalLike) => {

        if (totalLike !== null) {

          console.log("totalLike: " + totalLike);
          totalAmount = totalLike;
          return totalAmount;

        } else {
          throw totalAmount;
        }

      })
      .then((totalAmount) => {

        return admin.database().ref(`/OldNewKey`).child(fixedId).once('value');

      })
      .then((oldPostKeyShot) => {

        if (!oldPostKeyShot.exists()) {
          oldPostKey = fixedId;
        } else {
          oldPostKey = oldPostKeyShot.val();
        }

        return admin.database().ref(`/Posts`).child(oldPostKey).transaction();

      })
      .then((postRefShot) => {

        if (postRefShot === null) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return postRefShot;
        }

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return admin.database().ref().child('Send').child(fixedId).set(null);
      });
  )
}
```

Comment: If it works the way you want, then there's not a problem, right?

Comment: Now I can see that the catch() method is executing. Why?

Comment: Log the error it delivers?